# Как отследить появление определённого слова с помощью mutation observer и выполнить click по элементу

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, который мне кликает по элементу при его обнаружении. А как сделать так, что-бы click происходил по этому элементу при появлении слова Hello на странице?

```
<p class="comment-text">Hello</p>

new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
     if (Node.matches('.icn.icn-light-gray.icn-close.h')) Node.click();
     else {
        let Eldel = Node.querySelector('.icn.icn-light-gray.icn-close.h');
        if (Eldel) Eldel.click();
      }
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал небольшой стенд. При нажатии кнопки create hello в div добавляется p с текстом Hello и классом comment-text, а на событие вставки срабатывает onCLick кнопки target.

```js
new MutationObserver(Mutations => {
  const targetElementSelector = '.icn.icn-light-gray.icn-close.h';

  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {

        // проверяем, что появился Hello
        if (Node.matches('.comment-text') && Node.innerText === 'Hello') {
          // ищем элемент, кот надо кликнуть
          const targetElement = document.querySelector(targetElementSelector);
          if (targetElement) {
            targetElement.click();
          }
        }

        if (Node.matches(targetElementSelector)) {
          Node.click();
        } else {
          let Eldel = Node.querySelector(targetElementSelector);
          if (Eldel) Eldel.click();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

const onAddHello = () => {
  const helloContainer = document.querySelector('.helloContainer');
  if (helloContainer) {
    const hello = document.createElement('p');
    hello.innerText = 'Hello';
    hello.className = 'comment-text';
    helloContainer.appendChild(hello);
  }
}

const onCLickTarget = () => {
  alert('Target was clicked')
}
```

```css
.helloContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="icn icn-light-gray icn-close h" onclick="onCLickTarget()">target</button>
  <div class="helloContainer">
  </div>
  <button class="helloBtn" type="button" onclick="onAddHello()">create hello</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: chagins, у меня ваш код делает клик в независимости какое слово.  Может это важно, незнаю. Слово оно появляется не просто так, оно вписывается в текстовое поле `<div class="message-form-text-wrap">` после нажатия кнопки Отправить на странице появляется такое чуть сокращу: `<div id="fsimp_comment_333376444" class="fsr-photo-comment-block nclear tr-opacity-03" data-commentid="333376444">..........<p class="comment-text">Hello</p><div class="icn icn-light-gray icn-close h" title="Удалить комментарий" onclick="fsrating.viewer.imgDeleteComment(this)"></div></div>`